# Create string based on values in multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle 11G

- Table1 has T1_ID
- Table2 has T1_ID and a string (BIN_STR) representing a binary number

  1. if Table1.T1_ID is not in Table2 return is a string of 0s
  2. if Table1.T1_ID is found only once in Table2 the return is the string in Table2
  3. if Table1.T1_ID is found multiple times in Table2 the return needs to be the bitwise OR of the strings in Table2.

Example:

Table1

```
T1_ID 
    1 
    2 
    3
```

Table2 has these records

```
T1_ID   BIN_STR 
    2    '0101'
    3    '0100'
    3    '1000'
```

Result set needs to have

```
T1_ID   BIN_STR 
    1    '0000'
    2    '0101'
    3    '1100'
```

I have:

```
SELECT Tbl1.T1_ID,
       CASE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2 Tbl2 WHERE Tbl1.T1_ID = Tbl2.T1_ID)
         WHEN 0 THEN '0000'
         WHEN 1 THEN (SELECT Tbl2.BIN_STR FROM Table2 Tbl2 WHERE Tbl1.T1_ID = Tbl2.T1_ID)
         ELSE ???
       END AS "BINSTR"
FROM Table1 Tbl1
```

I know this can be done with a custom function call from a stored procedure. Is there any way to do it in SQL PLUS?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is the bitwise or aggregation function.  And, Oracle provides it (see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/group-by-functions.html#function_bit-or).

You need to convert the values to a BIGINT.  This assumes that you have fewer than 64 bits in the string:

```
select t1_id, cast(bit_or(cast(bin_str as bigint)) as varchar(255))
from table2
group by t1_id
```

Answer (score 0):

there's a few ways to do this in SQL 11g. here's the MODEL clause in action:

```
SQL> with data as (select t1.t1_id, nvl(t2.bin_str, '0000') bin_str
  2    from table1 t1
  3         left outer join table2 t2
  4                      on t1.t1_id = t2.t1_id)
  5  select t1_id, new_bin_str bin_str
  6    from (select *
  7    from data
  8   model
  9   partition by (t1_id)
 10   dimension by (row_number() over (partition by t1_id order by bin_str) rn )
 11   measures (bin_str, cast(null as varchar2(16)) new_bin_str,
 12   count(*) over (partition by t1_id ) c)
 13  rules (
 14  new_bin_str[any] order by rn  =
 15                    case when bin_str[cv() - 1 ] is null
 16               then bin_str[cv()]
 17                        else cast(utl_raw.bit_or(new_bin_str[cv()-1],bin_str[cv()]) as varchar2(16))
 18           end ))
 19   where c = rn;

     T1_ID BIN_STR
---------- --------------------
         1 0000
         2 0101
         3 1100
```

let's break this down.

```
SQL> with data as (select t1.t1_id, nvl(t2.bin_str, '0000') bin_str
  2    from table1 t1
  3         left outer join table2 t2
  4                      on t1.t1_id = t2.t1_id)
```

that's just our base query with all data in it that we're interested in.

now we need to XOR (available through utl_raw.bit_or) this and only show the final result per T1_ID.

the model clause can do this for us. first we define a "partition" as we want the calculations isolated to a specific T1_ID.

```
  9   partition by (t1_id)
```

next up, we apply an order to each row, so that we do things the same way each time. ie for T1_ID = 3 you have 0101 and 1100 so we want to do `0101 XOR 1100` and compute that  result. if there was a third binary "0001", we'd want to do `0101 XOR 1100 = res` then `res XOR 0001` and so on. and we're only interested in the final result, so we can use a row number to filter this for us in the end:

```
 10   dimension by (row_number() over (partition by t1_id order by bin_str) rn )
```

and we'll maintain a count of rows per `T1_ID` too:

```
 12   count(*) over (partition by t1_id ) c)
```

i.e when `rn = c` this is the final result in the dataset for each `T1_ID`.

the measures clause

```
 11   measures (bin_str, cast(null as varchar2(16)) new_bin_str,
```

will now be what we are operating on. i.e. `bin_str`, but also, you see i've defined a blank column `new_bin_str`. this will be our holding column that holds the result of the XOR operation.

now the computation part is the part that does the XOR:

14  new_bin_str[any] order by rn  =
 15                    case when bin_str[cv() - 1 ] is null
 16               then bin_str[cv()]
 17                        else cast(utl_raw.bit_or(new_bin_str[cv()-1],bin_str[cv()]) as varchar2(16))
 18           end ))

so what that is saying is, for every row (new_bin_str[ANY]) for the 1st row just use the value of `bin_str` but for every subsequent row we take the prior `new_bin_str` and XOR this to the current `bin_str` value. this give us the following output:

```
     T1_ID         RN BIN_STR              NEW_BIN_STR               C
---------- ---------- -------------------- ---------------- ----------
         1          1 0000                 0000                      1
         2          1 0101                 0101                      1
         3          1 0100                 0100                      2
         3          2 1000                 1100                      2
```

you can see now that NEW_BIN_STR has our result that we need but it also has all the intermdeiate "workings out". so we filter on c=rn to end up with:

```
     T1_ID         RN BIN_STR              NEW_BIN_STR               C
---------- ---------- -------------------- ---------------- ----------
         1          1 0000                 0000                      1
         2          1 0101                 0101                      1
         3          2 1000                 1100                      2
```

and in the outer select i just select the `T1_ID` and `NEW_BIN_STR`.

other ways could be recursive factor sub querys, a user defined aggregate (eg like listagg but one that did XOR) or even perhaps xquery (haven't thought that one out but it may have the power to do it too).